# Como realizar una operacion de resta multiplicacion y suma automaticamente en html

Tags: php, html

```
<tr>
<td>
    <label class="title">Chocolate: </label><br>
 <label><?php echo $ver[4];  ?></label>
</td> 

<td> 
    <input type="hidden" name="ChocolateIn" value="<?php echo $ver[4];  ?>">

    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="Chocolate" placeholder="Saldo" required >
</td>

    <input type="hidden" id="preciochocolate"  value="500"/>


<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm"  id="RChocolate" name="RChocolate" value="0" readonly>

</td>
```

Limonada:

```
    <label><?php echo $ver[5];  ?></label>
</td>

<td>  
    <input type="hidden" name="LimonadaIn" value="<?php echo $ver[5];  ?>">

    <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="Limonada" placeholder="Saldo" required>
</td>

    <input type="hidden" id="preciolimonada" value="350"/>

<td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="RLimonada" name="RLimonada" value="0" readonly >
</td>
```

**Nesesito que reste el valor del input "ChocolateIn" que resulta de una consulta sql.
lo reste con el valor del input "Chocolate" que lo ingrese el usuaio manualmente 
el resultado de esa operacion lo multiplique con el valor del input "preciochocolate"
el resultado de eso quede almacenado en el input "RChocolate"
asi mismo con la otra fila de "Limonada"

al final me muestre la suma de los input "RChocolate y RLimonada" sin hacer uso de botones gracias soy nuevo pero aprendo rapido, uso php html, como debo de realizar estas operaciones gracias **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca esto codigo javascript despues de todo tu html:

```html
<script>
 
 document.querySelector("input[name=Chocolate]").addEventListener("input", function(e){
    var chocoin= document.querySelector("input[name=ChocolateIn]").value;
 var chocolate= e.target.value;  
 var chocoprecio= document.getElementById("preciochocolate").value; 
 var rescho= ( parseInt(chocoin) - parseInt( chocolate)) * parseInt(  chocoprecio);

 document.querySelector("input[name=RChocolate]").value=    (  chocolate.length == 0 ||  rescho === NaN || rescho === undefined) ? 0 : rescho ;


});

   document.querySelector("input[name=Limonada]").addEventListener("input", function(e){
    var limoin= document.querySelector("input[name=LimonadaIn]").value;
 var limonada=  e.target.value; 
 var limoprecio= document.getElementById("preciolimonada").value;
 var reslim= ( parseInt(limoin) - parseInt( limonada)) * parseInt(  limoprecio);
 document.querySelector("input[name=RLimonada]").value=    (  limonada.length == 0 || reslim === NaN || reslim === undefined) ? 0 : reslim ;
/**************************/
//nueva linea a agregar
var totalf= rescho +reslim;
document.getElementById("result-final").value= totalf;
/**agrega un input a tu formulario

<input type="number" id="result-final" readonly/>
   }) ;

 

 </script>
```

Los eventos tipo input son utiles para campos donde vas tipeando valores y quieres capturar sus valores reales en el momento que escribes nuevos digitos.
Ademas no necesitaras botones con este codigo

Comment: Muhcas gracias funciono a la perfeccion, como la varibles que agrego son muchas, como debo de implementar el codigo para usarlo no al final de mi html, si no, en otra pagina .js para que no quede tan cargado una pagina con tanto codigo gracias

Comment: copia todo eso codigo javascript (pero sin los tags <script></script>), solo el contenido y lo guardas en un archivo con extension js, de preferencia guardalo en la misma ubicacion de tu archivo html.  Y despues del body agregas esta linea:    <script type="text/javascript" src="tuarchivo.js"></script>

Comment: listo lo hice como me dijiste me sale este error

`operaciones.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at operaciones.js:1 `

Comment: Si te da ese error, lo mas probable es que no esta encontrando el elemento html al que se pretende asignar el evento, donde haz colocado la linea de <script.... ? Postealo y analizaremos que es lo que falla

Comment: como me dijiste lo puse debajo del body 
`<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Menu</title>
 
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="operaciones.js"></script>`

Comment: Ah ya comprend0!!  Mira entendiste un poquito mal =), te dije al final del body es decir:      todo tu html, luego este </body> y luego de esta tag de cierre colocalo

Comment: listo jajajaj funciono muchas gracias, te puedo molestar preguntando como sumo todos los totales para ponerlo en una variable "Totales" al final del formulario .. demasiado agradecido por su tiempo y conocimiento

Comment: Te refieres a sumar lo de RChocolate y RLimonada, y colocar el resultado en un campo de formulario verdad?

Comment: si correcto, sumar esos campos que se generaron con el codigo y ponerlos en un input totales "ReadOnly" gracias

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, notaras las nuevas lineas que agregue. Tambien crearas un nuevo input en el html, en mi ejemplo le puse un id  "result-final", el cual mostrara el total definitivo

Comment: me sale este error 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: rescho is not defined
    at operaciones.js:168`, el input "result-final" debe ir dento de "});" porque yo lo tengo en otra hoja de codigo

Comment: listo ya solucione ese error, pero no me esta dando el resultado de la suma y no me aparece erro.. seguire revisando. muchas gracias por toda tu ayuda demasiado

Comment: sigue sin funcionarme la suma no me aparece ningun error, quedo pendiente de la ayuda que me puedan dar

Answer (score 1):

listo ya pude realizar la suma de los inputs dinamicos, busque en foros de nuestra plataforma y encontre este codigo que me funciono, sumando las clases. Muchas graciasa Sonia Toledo por todo su apoyo.

```js
    <script >

  function suma() {
      var add = 0;
      $('.form-control-sm').each(function() {
          if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
              add += Number($(this).val());
          }
      });
      $('#totalventa').val(add);
    
  };
</script>
```